# How to I get proper spacing in this? (Screenshot attached)

Tags: html, css, jsp

[image]

The code sample is:

```
<body>
  <h4 style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:120px;">Mark skills to add</h4>
    <div class=""style="position:absolute;top:170px;left:120px;width:1100px;background-color:#CCC;padding-bottom:50px;padding:20px;">
        <form class="" action="AddSkills">
          <h4 style="">Business Accounting Human Resources and Legal</h4>
            <p style="float:left;width:200px;height:30px;"><input type="checkbox" value="79" name="skill0"/> Accounting</p> 
            <p style="float:left;width:200px;height:30px;"><input type="checkbox" value="80" name="skill1"/>    Audit </p>  
          <h4 style="">Data Entry and Admin</h4>
            <p style="float:left;width:200px;height:30px;"><input type="checkbox" value="56" name="skill6"/> Article submission</p> 
            <p style="float:left;width:200px;height:30px;"><input type="checkbox" value="57" name="skill7"/>    Data entry </p> 
          <input type="hidden" value="<%=tot%>" name="tot"/>
          <input style=""type="submit" value="Add selected skills" class="btn btn-danger">
       </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

I want the output to be like the one when using `display:inline;` (inside `<p></p>`) and the spacing to be like the one when using `float:left;`(inside `<p></p>`)

How do I do this?

P.S. -> I am fetching the contents from database on a jsp page. The code here is from the view-source

Comment: Try `display: inline-block`

Comment: Thanks :D .. you can post it as an answer if you like. @AnupamBasak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using inline-block for paragraph and give width using percentages as below code

```
  <body>
  <h4>Mark skills to add</h4>
    <div>
        <form class="" action="AddSkills">
          <h4 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">Business Accounting Human Resources and Legal</h4>
            <div style="width:100% !important;display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px;clear:both;">
            <p style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:22%;"><input type="checkbox" value="79" name="skill0"/> Accounting</p>    
                <p style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:22%;"><input type="checkbox" value="80" name="skill1"/>   Audit </p> </div> 
          <h4 style="margin:0px;padding:0px;display:block;width:100%;clear:both;">Data Entry and Admin</h4>
          <div style="clear:both">  <p style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:22%;"><input type="checkbox" value="56" name="skill6"/> Article submission</p>    
            <p style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:22%;"><input type="checkbox" value="57" name="skill7"/>   Data entry </p> </div>

       </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with this many `div` and inline styles use `table` add each title as one row and choices as cells of the row under it. then set the table width to 100%